# vim executing diff command twice

Tags: vim, diff

I found a peculiar behavior with my vim: It executes every diff command twice and I'm not sure why.

<strike>(I'm running this on Windows, I'm suspecting this has something to do with it.)</strike> As per the answer, it hasn't.

So I have this in my vimrc:

```
set diffexpr=MyDiff()

function! DoubleQuoteCond(s)
  return a:s =~ ' ' ? '"' . a:s . '"' : a:s
endfunction

function! MyDiff()
   if &shell =~ '\<cmd'
    let prog = DoubleQuoteCond($VIMRUNTIME . '\diff')
  else
    let prog = substitute($VIMRUNTIME, ' ', '" ', '') . '\diff')
  endif

  let opt = '-a --binary'
  if &diffopt =~ 'icase' | let opt .= ' -i' | endif
  if &diffopt =~ 'iwhite' | let opt .= ' -b' | endif

  let file1 = DoubleQuoteCond(v:fname_in)
  let file2 = DoubleQuoteCond(v:fname_new)
  let file3 = DoubleQuoteCond(v:fname_out)

  let cmdline = join([prog, opt, file1, file2, '>', file3], ' ')

  " no silent execute for debugging reasons
  execute '!' . cmdline 
endfunction
```

Pretty simple function that builds a `cmdline` like this one:

```
"C:\Program Files\Vim\vim\diff" -a --binary C:\Temp\VIoCC20.tmp C:\Temp\VInCC21.tmp > C:\Temp\VIdCC22.tmp
```

Now this happens:

- This cmdline is executed, a cmd window pops up, the file `VIdCC22.tmp` is created.
  Since it's no `silent execute` I have to press enter to continue.
- Right after that vim executes the same *again*, as if `MyDiff()` was called twice.
- Now vim picks up the diff output and displays it as expected.

When I set `diffexpr` to `''` the diff shell command is executed only once.

Where does the second execution come from? What can I do to prevent it (other than not using a custom `diffexpr`, of course)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set `'diffexpr'`

> Vim will do a test if the diff output looks alright.

(This is from `:help E810`.)

You cannot avoid this. However, you can check for the test, as Vim passes constant dummy file contents ("line1" and "line2", respectively), and short-circuit the external command execution in this case, like this:

```
if
\   getfsize(v:fname_in) <= 6 &&
\   getfsize(v:fname_new) <= 6 &&
\   readfile(v:fname_in, 0, 1)[0] ==# 'line1' &&
\   readfile(v:fname_new, 0, 1)[0] ==# 'line2'
    return
endif
```

Comment: Bummer! I've not looked at the contents of the files. How would I short-circuit the command execution? I mean, vim expects the output file to look a certain way, so I'd have to let it do its thing, wouldn't I?

Comment: I've added an example implementation to my answer.

Comment: I suppose vim reads the contents of `v:fname_out` after the first invocation of `MyDiff()`, so not executing the test command will not help me.

Comment: No, but you could fake the output (e.g. with `writefile()`) in a way that does not invoke your actual diff and therefore forces you to acknowledge with Enter.

Comment: Yes, I could do that. OTOH when I use `silent execute` I don't have to press enter, either. I've been using the diff feature for years but noticed this behavior only recently. I was just wondering where the second execution came from. Now that I understand it, I guess I will just leave it as it is.